# The type java.lang.charSequence cannot be resolved to a type error

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors, aspectj, eclipse-kepler

I have this following aspectJ class method which gives me the error,The type java.lang.charSequence  cannot be resolved to a type error.

```
before(String name) throws ServiceLayerException:
    call(void ServiceImplementation.displayBookDetails(String)) && args(name){
    String sqlText = "SELECT * FROM Books WHERE Name='"+name+"'";
    logger1.info("Before Aspect :: Display Book Details of " + name);
    System.out.println(sqlText);
    connectToDbAndDisplayBookDetails(sqlText);

}
```

I am using Eclipse Kepler and my this project is built using jdk 1.7. I tried installing jdk 1.8 patch for Kepler but that doesn't help. It doesn't get installed and stops during the installation process. Please help.

Comment: Is `java.lan` in the actual error message or is that `java.lang`? Also, SQL injection alert

Comment: its java.lang. Sorry typing mistake

Comment: Is this a compilation error? Which line exactly?

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to Luna, just so as to check if it is an Eclipse problem or something else?

Answer (score 0):

It can be a sneaky Java8 interface problem.
In Java8 the charSequence has a default method attached.

If you are using it from Java7 compiler doesn't allow you to use default methods.

Try to fix the jdk 1.8 patch setup.